# How to write an outlook add-in using unmanaged code (C++/Delphi)?

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, outlook, outlook-addin

I developed an Outlook Add-in using C#.

I want do completely avoid being punished for slowing down Outlook startup.

Therefore I would like to create a "Loader"-Add-in. It's written in C++/Delphi and does nothing but enabling the C#-Add-in after itself has beeing loaded.

There are a lot of hints on stackoverflow, etc. but no straightforward documentation available.

Questions:

1. Is there any straightforward documentation about how to write an Outlook Add-in using C++/Delphi?
2. Is there any documentation about how to write an Add-in which enables a secondary Add-in?

Comment: In the first place, you should probably optimize your add-in so that it loads faster. Maybe defer some initialization some times after the load, for example when it is really needed. You could also split your add-in in several DLL or COM objects that will be loaded on demand, later after the initial load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course - just implement a creatable COM object that (besides `IUnknown`) also exposes `_IDTExtensibility2` interface - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/extensibility.idtextensibility2?view=visualstudiosdk-2019. You will also need to add its class name to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins`.

If you want to support ribbon or task panes, you will aso need to implement `IRibbonExtensibility` and/or `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are no straightforward documentation about how to write an Outlook Add-in using C++/Delphi, because outlook add-ins has two models

1. VSTO (old) is designed for .Net Framework and c#. Works via COM (Microsoft.Office.Interop.*).
2. Add-ins is designed for TypeScript (outlook web add-ins).

More about loading VSTO add-in,  you can read in [Architecture of VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/architecture-of-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019)

So, there are no easy way to write managed dll for VSTO via c++. There are right way is read documentation about VSTO architecture, and solve perfomance problem in loading add-in.

Comment: Thanks. Still I wonder why then Microsoft suggests writing unmanaged add-ins: "Prefer native COM add-ins over managed add-ins since managed add-ins must incur the overhead of loading the .NET Framework during Outlook startup." https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-com-add-ins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/customizing-outlook-using-com-add-ins

Comment: @Abid I also wonder that. Today I read that article by accident.